# Find tag in XML-File

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have xml-files like:

```
<article>
<MainText>
    <Big> HDhsdjdsd </Big>
    <Small> jdhdhksdj </Small>
    <Big><text> jsdhjsadh </text> <footnote> 1 </footnote>  <text> hsdhsdh </text> </Big>
</MainText>
</article>
```

My question is: Since "footnote" is not every time at the same position (i.e. after a text-tag; but always in "MainText"), I don't know how I can get this tag in general.
Can anybody show me how this is possible? I tried it with "findall", but this does not work. 
Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: If you showed *how* you tried with `findall`, we might be able to say _why_ that attempt didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.//MainText//footnote` xpath expression. It will find `footnote` tag anywhere inside the `MainText`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<article>
<MainText>
    <Big> HDhsdjdsd </Big>
    <Small> jdhdhksdj </Small>
    <Big><text> jsdhjsadh </text> <footnote> 1 </footnote>  <text> hsdhsdh </text> </Big>
</MainText>
</article>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

print tree.find('.//MainText//footnote').text.strip()
```

prints `1`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added an additional question ;)

Comment: @MarkF6 this is not how things work here. The question you've added is not related to the initial one. Better create a separate question here on SO. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465147/get-text-of-a-xml-file-but-ignore-some-content